# How to understand frustration phase factor?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, ferromagnetism

For a system with basis $|m\rangle$, where $m=1,2,3...$
The frustration phase factor is defined in any path $C=\{m_1m_2...m_\alpha\}$ as:
$$\Phi_C=\arg[(-1)^\alpha H_{m_1m_2} H_{m_2m_3}\dotsb H_{m_\alpha m_1}]$$
The product of elements of Hamiltonian can be understood directly from the view of path integral, but what's the origin of  $(-1)^\alpha$  ? And why the physical phenomenon will be so different if $\Phi_C$ is non-zero?

In the other words, I am confused that why the sign of elements of Hamiltonian is so important?